# function to find the center of map in jxmap

Tags: java, swing, maps

enter code hereIs there any function in jxmap to find the center of map.
I want to find the center of the map given in the following code.
Is there is any way to find the center please suggest.

```
 `GeocoderRequest request = new GeocoderRequest(map);
 request.setAddress("30.332823,78.050087");
getServices().getGeocoder().geocode(request, new GeocoderCallback(map) 
{
@Override
public void onComplete(GeocoderResult[] result, GeocoderStatus status)
 {
  if (status == GeocoderStatus.OK)`
 {

                            Marker marker = new Marker(map);
                            System.out.println(result[0].toString());
                            marker.setPosition(result[0].getGeometry().getLocation());                                

                            final InfoWindow window = new InfoWindow(map);
                            window.setContent("Hello, World!");
                            window.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, from the doc:

```
// Getting the associated map object
final Map map = getMap();
// Setting the map center
map.setCenter(new LatLng(map, 35.91466, 10.312499));
// Setting initial zoom value
map.setZoom(2.0);
```

https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps#features